# Display HTML table inside a DIV using Javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript, php, rendering, highmaps

I am working on displaying a table that lists things based on what state was selected in HighMaps during drill down:

Code Snippet:

```
                switch (e.point.name) {
                    case 'California':
                        $('#table').html('');
                        break;
                    case 'Virginia':
                        $('#table').html('');
                        break;
                    default:
                        $('#table').html('');
                        break;
                }
<div id="table"></div>
```

The table is dynamically generated by taking data from DB for each state using PHP. Table structure looks like this:

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Company List - State</h3>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Company Name</th>
                                    <th>County</th>
                                    <th>Details</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Company 1</td>
                                    <td>Test County</td>
                                    <td>Company details.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Company 2</td>
                                    <td>Test County</td>
                                    <td>Company details.</td>
                                </tr>
                                    <td>Company 3</td>
                                    <td>Test County</td>
                                    <td>Company details.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The generated table output that does inside .html('') looks like this:

```
 $('#table').html('<div class="container"> <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title text-center">Company List - California</h3></div><table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table"><thead><tr><th>Company Name</th><th>County</th><th>Details</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Company 1</td><td>Test County</td><td>Company details are available to ACMA members only.</td></tr><tr><td>Company 2</td><td>Test County</td><td>Company details are available to ACMA members only.</td></tr><td>Company 3</td><td>Test County</td><td>Company details.</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div>');
```

Everything works well when the list of companies is small. Once The number of companies per state gets bigger and the generated table code becomes longer things stop working. I tested it out. If I take the part of generated code that is too long and delete half of it then everything starts working again.

Is there a limit on how many characters can go inside .html(); ? Is there a more efficient way to display these tables?

Comment: Well there are fifty states. So prerendering in memory is always faster. Build the table in memory using a `documentFragment` and append it to the `table`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an example snippet I could take a look at? My JS knowledge is very limited but when I see examples I can pick it up pretty quickly.

Comment: You're building the HTML in PHP? Is it returned via AJAX?

Comment: No. I have a php function that generates the code after its pulled from DB then I "clean/format" it and just copy/paste it into the script.

Comment: You're doing this manually?

Comment: At the moment, yes. I am trying to get everything to work first. Once I have everything in place, I will go back and break it down to improve it. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: No not really, I don't get the purpose of generating the HTML server side and then copy paste it into your source code. What's your intended design?

Comment: This is just while I am testing the overall functionality of this thing. I will insert the tables dynamically before the final version. For now I just need a quick way to see what this  thing will look like.

Comment: Does it actually stop working, or is it just slow?

Comment: @Ondkloss it breaks. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/mtwpddbp/. First case is fine but the second it much longer and doesn't work. Syntax is correct. If you delete half of the code inside the second .html('') it will start working again.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the append function within some specific selector like the one you are using currently $("#table").append(); check the link mentioned below:

http://api.jquery.com/append/